# Lost authentication when using GraphQL subscriptions with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, spring-graphql

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-graphql` for my GraphQL server application. I protected the application with basic authentication using Spring security.
GraphQL subscription are used to return a type with a subtype. As soon as subscription returns a type, authentication gets lost from security context.

Here is short version of my configuration:

```
type Post  {
    id: String!
    title: String! 
    author: Author!
}

type Author  {
    id: String!
    name: String!
}

type Subscription {
    getNewPost: Post
}

@SchemaMapping(typeName = "Post", field = "author")
public Author getAuthor(Post post) {
    return this.appService.getAuthorById(post.getAuthorId());
}

@Bean
Many<Post> publisher() {
    return Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
}

@SubscriptionMapping("getNewPost")
public Publisher<Post> getNewPost() {
    return this.publisher.asFlux();
}

public Post createPost(CreatePostInput postInput) {
    ...     
    this.publisher.tryEmitNext(post);
    ...
}
```

Everything works as expected until subscription returns first object. After that security context becomes empty and any following request gets redirected to login page.

I noticed two things:

- In case that object that subscription returns (`Post` in this example) doesn't contain nested object (`Author`), everything works as it should
- With Java Kickstart everything works as it should

I created an example application for reproducing this issue: https://github.com/stojsavljevic/graphql-security-issue

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The issue is solved with Spring Boot 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

According to Rossen Stoyanchev's presentation at Spring IO last May ([which you can watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMZckqbPGq0)), Spring for GraphQL has a layered architecture that has a Web transport layer at the top (be it HTTP or Websocket), then comes the GraphQL engine, and then the Data Controllers.

It's at this last level that we find the Components, like a mutation or a query service, or also one of this "service" operations invoked by a Controller method.
Spring for GraphQL makes sure that the Security context (e.g. the SecurityFilterChain) gets propagated through the GraphQL engine layer and remains available.
For that to work in your example, according to what I saw in your Github repository I believe you should use a @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") annotation in your methods.

```
    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    public Post createPost(CreatePostInput postInput) {
    
    Post post = new Post("1", postInput.getTitle(), postInput.getAuthorId());
    // not actually saving anything
    
    // publish newly created Post
    this.publisher.tryEmitNext(post);
    
    return post;
}
```

Make sure to enable method level security as well.
Hope it helps.

Note: For the Security part of Rossen's talk [go to 24:05 onwards](https://youtu.be/FMZckqbPGq0?t=1444).

Comment: Hi Julio, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, enabling method level security doesn't help. My feeling is that this is the bug somehow related to schema mapping. As I stated before, everything works well if subtype is not used in a subscription response. I tried adding `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` and `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` but without any success.